# Why is Equals() being not called for the all objects while adding to collection

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I have a type which I am using as key in the IDictionary. The type is as following

```
public  class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Employee emp = obj as Employee;
        if (emp != null)
            return emp.Name.Equals(this.Name);
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now I have created a dictionary as following in my main as following

```
 IDictionary<Employee, int> empCollection = new Dictionary<Employee, int>();
        Employee emp1 = new Employee() { Name = "abhi", ID = 1 };
        Employee emp2 = new Employee() { Name = "vikram", ID = 2 };
        Employee emp3 = new Employee() { Name = "vikram", ID = 3 };

        empCollection.Add(emp1, 1);
        empCollection.Add(emp2, 2);
        empCollection.Add(emp3, 3);
```

Now while debugging I found out that when emp1 is added to the collection only GetHashCode method is called of the key type, after that when emp2 is added to the collection only GetHashCode  method is called again but in the case of emp3 both GetHashCode and Equals methods are called.

May be it looks too naive being asking this question but why isn't Equals method not called when eqImp2 object is added to collection. What is happening inside. Please explain.

Comment: `emp2` and `emp3` have the same hashcodes, base on your implementation of GetHashCode

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overridden?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The dictionary and all other similar containers use the hashcode as a quick-and-dirty check: different hashcodes mean that two objects are **definitely** not equal; identical hashcodes do not mean anything. The documentation of [`GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) specifies this behavior by saying

> If two objects compare as equal, the GetHashCode method for each
>   object must return the same value. However, if two objects do not
>   compare as equal, the GetHashCode methods for the two object do not
>   have to return different values.

Your `emp1` and `emp2` generate different hashcodes, so the dictionary does not need to run `Equals`; it already knows they are not equal. On the other hand, `emp2` and `emp3` generate the same hashcode so the dictionary must call `Equals` to definitely determine if they are indeed equal, or if the identical hashcode was just the result of chance.

Comment: Excellent answer, the only thing I am still curious about is the dictionary's reaction to a duplicate being added.  I imagine it throws an exception?

Answer (score 1):

In your example the `GetHashCode` looks at the Name hash code. emp3 has the same name as emp2 , ("vikram"). They are equal given the hash code so it further looks using `Equals`.

Answer (score 1):

emp2 and emp3 have the same key. This will cause a "key collision" in the dictionary. It first called GetHashCode() and determined the hash codes were the same. It then ensures they're the same by calling Equals(). The code from Dictionary is:

```
int num = this.comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 2147483647;
...
if (this.entries[i].hashCode == num && this.comparer.Equals(this.entries[i].key, key))
```

Obviously, if the hashcodes don't match, it never has to call Equals.

You should get a tool like ILSpy and then you can look at the code and find the answer yourself.

Comment: I didn't know that tool existed - coolest thing I've seen in ages, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you continue this experiment, you'll observe some behavior which is specific to the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implementation, and some behavior that is required due to the way you implemented `GetHashCode`.

First, it's important to understand the role of `GetHashCode` and `Equals` when comparing objects for equality. Additional information is available on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden), but I'll repeat the basic rules here:

1. The `Equals` method establishes exactly which objects are equal and which objects are not. All necessary checks need to be performed in this method for a final determination before returning.
2. A *hash code* is a value calculated from the value of your object. Typically it is much smaller than the original object (in our case the hash code is a 4 byte integer) and not necessarily unique. However it is much faster to compute and compare to each other than the original objects themselves.

   - When hash codes do not need to be unique, different hash codes indicate different objects (i.e. `Equals` will definitely return false), but equal hash codes do not mean anything (i.e. `Equals` could return true or false).

Collections which associate values with a key object (e.g. `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` in .NET, or `Map<K, V>` in Java) take advantage of the hash codes to improve implementation efficiency. However, since the documentation for [`Object.GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) specifically does not require the results to be unique, these collections cannot rely on the hash codes alone for proper functionality. **When two objects have the same hash code, only a call to `Equals` can distinguish them.** The case you describe for the insertion of `emp3` falls into this case: the [`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add`] method needs to throw an `ArgumentException` if you are trying to insert the same value, and only a call to `Equals` can determine if the new key `emp3` is equal to the previously inserted `emp3`.

**Additional implementation characteristics**

The particular collection implementation may result in more calls to `GetHashCode` than you anticipate. For example, when the internal storage of a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) is resized, an implementation might call `GetHashCode` for every object stored in the collection. Collections based on a [binary-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) or [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) might only call `GetHashCode` once (if the results are cached in the tree structure), or might need to call `GetHashCode` for multiple objects during every insertion or lookup operation (if the results are not cached).

Sometimes hash table implementations need to call `GetHashCode` for multiple objects, or perhaps even `Equals` for objects with different hash codes due to the way they use modulo arithmetic to place keys into "buckets". The specific characteristics of this vary from one implementation to the next.

Answer (score 0):

That is because **GetHashCode** is a shortcut.
C# will first call **GetHashCode** which is supposed to be fast executing. 
If two objects have different HashCodes then there is no need to call the, assumingly, more expensive **Equals** method.
Only if they have the same HashCode then it will call **Equals**. That is because HashCode is not guaranteed to be unique